# How can I format input field to a percentage value?

Tags: type-conversion, sapui5, user-input, formatter

Using SAPUI5 xml view, I would like to add a formatter onto an input field. Depending on what the user enters (digits) I would like to see a trailing % attached to the value.

```
so if userinput value = "99" ---> "99%" or ".5" ---> "50%"
```

Looking at the datatypes, I'm not sure there is an 'out of box' solution to format an input value to a percentage. Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

```
 <Input
    id="percentGrowth"
    type="Text"
    value="{path:'inputModel>/myPath', type:'sap.ui.model.type.Float', contraints: {maximum : 1}}"   >
</Input>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should use a formatter 
[Formatter sapui5](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/07/e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8/content.htm)

For example

```
   <Input
    id="percentGrowth"
    type="Text"
    value="{path:'inputModel>/myPath', 
    type:'sap.ui.model.type.Float', 
    contraints: {maximum : 1}, 
    formatter:'.myFormatter'}"   >
</Input>
```

And then add in your controller the function

```
myController.prototype.myFormatter(value){
   return  value + "%";
}
```

For further details you have an example in this link to the [SDN](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3683523)

Comment: For me this breaks the two way binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SAPUI5 percentage formatter **NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format()**:

```
   <Input
    id="percentGrowth"
    type="Text"
    value="{path:'inputModel>/myPath', 
    type:'sap.ui.model.type.Float', 
    contraints: {maximum : 1}, 
    formatter:'.formatPercentage'}"   >
</Input>
```

In the controller:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/format/NumberFormat"
],function (NumberFormat) {
          formatPercentage: (number) => {
                return NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(number);
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Never forget to put **data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"** in bootstrap script while using Expression binding or Formatters.

Or even better use: **data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"**